# Core Data - Encryption / Decryption on iOS

Tags: ios4

I know that in iOS, if the .sqlite is updated / read by SQL statement, then SQLCipher can be used to do encryption and decryption.

Is there any suggestion if Core Data is used instead ? The requirements are:

- Core Data is used instead
- Backup via itune for the application data is still be encrypted

Thanks

Comment: Have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/523482/core-data-vs-sqlite-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the SQLite to be encrypted when the device is locked only, then the on-disk encryption feature introduced in iOS 4 is your answer.

Otherwise, you may need to encrypt stuff programmatically. Cf. [Core Data SQLite encryption?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285298/core-data-sqlite-encryption).

But AFAIK, there's no built-in support of any SQLite encryption feature in Core Data.